# How to create snmp agent from net-snmp

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I want to implement SNMP-agent for PowerPC board using net-snmp.
Previously it was implemented using SMASH. SMASH has a parser
which could read MIB and generate C code (blank function imlementation)

How do I get started?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a look to [Writing a MIB module](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/tutorial-4/agent/01-intro.html) [tutorial](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/tutorial-5/toolkit/mib_module/index.html).

Comment: seems your link have been changed: `There is currently no text in this page`

Answer (score 2):

Try to look at [mib2c](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/tutorial-5/toolkit/mib2c/index.html) tool from net-snmp. It will generate the snmp agent C code from the MIB. Then you have to only fulfill the return values to SNMP requests. Skeleton of responding to SNMP requests (get, set, get-next) are automatically done by generating.

Comment: After creating a MIB file I have put it in to the MIB folder and add the same into snmp.conf. After that generate the c code with mib2c tool. Now my questing is where to put that generated c file and header file.

Answer (score 0):

I took a different approach to this. In order to better integrate with my C++ ecosystem, and to obtain greater flexibility (particularly at scale), I:

- Had a pre-build step parse the result of `snmptranslate` (that is, the MIB tree) into a bunch of C++ maps and other containers for use in code
- Borrowed Net-SNMP's transport and PDU building functions
- But serviced requests myself upon receipt, using my C++ maps and the data already available to my application

This made notification generation trivial (I just needed some variant types to generate varbinds, a bit of PDU construction and then left the rest to Net-SNMP's transport feature), although for requests I did then have to implement table walking myself (and *GetNext*/*GetBulk*/*Set* are not trivial unless you avoid all tables, or at least avoid composite-index tables).

The result is a fast, robust and scalable SNMP agent with expressive code that's easy to maintain and to extend.

You don't say you're using C++, but this does give an idea of how you can cherry-pick Net-SNMP functionality without necessarily buying into its entire ecosystem.

Do note that I have no idea how SNMPv3 would fit into this model; I cleverly left the company before it became my problem. :)